# Встреча участников сообщества в Евросоюзе

Tags: обсуждение, встречи-сообщества

Дорогие коллеги, почему бы нам не организовать встречу участников в ЕС? У нас было много встреч в Москве, Питере, Минске и Новосибирске, но в ЕС ещё ни разу не было.

Давайте прикинем, скольких участников мы сможем собрать, и в каком из городов стоит проводить встречу. Просьба голосовать за города в ответах, и отписываться в комментариях, кто и куда сможет приехать.

Предлагаемый формат — посиделки с едой/напитками и разговорами на любые темы, кроме политики и всего неприятного.

Кажется, к нам сможет присоединиться Николас. Очень хотелось бы, чтобы все склоки и дрязги, которые происходили в последнее время, остались вне планируемой встречи, и встреча была бы просто хорошей и приятной.

---

Николас подготовил [форму для регистрации](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScTRCZKY_MnT0KE3Dmm1TZ3uvpFG5Ri_hVESwZxrHepd3EiKQ/viewform). Не забывайте, что ваши личные данные попадут к организаторам встречи, так что не оставляйте тех личных данных, которые вы не хотели бы оставлять.

---

**Обновление:** Голосование с большим отрывом выиграла Прага. К сожалению, отозвалось не так много участников на текущий момент. Ориентировочная дата — 17-18 ноября.

Comment: Калининград? А вообще, всё кроме Новосиба, имхо, Европа.

Comment: @alexolut, и Хабаровск -)?  Впрочем, я с 8-го по 20-е буду в Лимасоле. Если кто-то тоже собрался погреть пузо на Кипре, то можно встретиться там.

Comment: Всё от даты зависит. В Октябре точно не смогу.

Comment: @alexolut ок, разделим мир на Новосиб и Европу )

Comment: @avp да, Хабаровск — это тоже Новосиб )

Comment: @avp и даже Петропавловск-Камчатский, будь он в списке. Но его нет.

Comment: Кстати, в Киеве, насколько я помню, встреча планировалась, но не состоялась. Из-за бана организатора :)

Comment: @alexolut +1 за Калиниград (если 6-7 Окт).

Comment: Да можно было бы просто сказать, что встреча в Евросоюзе, тогда бы не надо было никаких сносок.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov: Хорошая идея, так и сделал

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Великобританию отметаем, значит? Или пока еще юридически нет ;)

Comment: @alexolut Ну во-первых, она ещё в ЕС, там ещё годы пройдут, пока они оформят выход (и то не факт), во-вторых, встреча на её территории вряд ли будет (пока Мюнхен или Прага обсуждаются), в-третьих, не знаю активных участников оттуда. Короче, бессмысленно это обсуждать.

Comment: Ну, мы организуем встречу в ЕС, а приезжать могут участники откуда хотят.

Comment: @VladD Я подготовил [форму](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScTRCZKY_MnT0KE3Dmm1TZ3uvpFG5Ri_hVESwZxrHepd3EiKQ/viewform). Было бы здорово ее добавить в ваш вопрос. В дальнейшем, какое решение бы не приняли, я свяжусь теми, кто откликнулся. Сейчас непонятно кто хочет и может присоединиться.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Может быть, имеет смысл создать форму не у гугла? У меня, например, вовсе нет экаунта в гугле, пришлось завести временный.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Спасибо! Добавил.

Comment: VladD, гуглоформу можно настроить, чтобы она заполнялась без входа в аккаунт. Просто там либо явно выставлено требованием на залогиненность, либо неявно через запрет на повторные голосования. // сс @NicolasChabanovsky

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky предлагаю не требовать, чтобы участники были залогинены в гугле. Правда, не у всех же есть учётка, и не все хотят раскрывать её.

Comment: @VladD Подскажите какую-другу форму можно использовать? Вероятно, в ней будет то же ограничение, что и в этой. Сейчас форма настроена на анонимные ответы (я не получаю почту), но с условием, что можно отвечать только один раз (чтобы не было спама).

Comment: @NickVolynkin Это механика Google Forms. Подскажите, как ее отключить?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Подскажете нам? ^^^

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, вот этот флажок (про ответ один раз) и надо снять. Иначе гугл будет требовать войти (вероятно, он определяет число ответов по адресу).

Comment: Жалко что мoё предложение так и не взлетело ;_;

Comment: @timob256: Думаю, причина в том, что иронию у вас было сложно отличить от агрессии.

Comment: @VladD да не, не из за этого, а из за того что я слишком точно описал киевское отношение к русскоязычным сообществам.

Comment: Очень хотелось бы попасть, да я живу фиг знает где...

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Исправьте `Пжалуйста` на `Пожалуйста` в форме

Comment: @timob256: Ну мне кажется не всё так грустно. Я вот сам в прошлом киевлянин.

Comment: @VladD "вот сам в прошлом киевлянин" со всеми в прошлом киевлянами можно найти общий язык . А вот с нынешними как то очень.

Comment: @VerNick Спасибо! Поправил.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky А Andrey NOP приезжал на собрания?

Comment: Геленджик! Можно реально хорошо и отдохнуть!

Comment: @Qwertiy Только как тогда от спама и шутников тогда спасаться?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, ну как-то нам спам в формы отзывов не шлют... Ссылки на профиль недостаточно? А шутники и так смогут гуглоаккаунт найти, с которого ответить.

Comment: Предлагаю еще Лондон, хотя я и не приеду. Он недалеко от Амстердама, хороший город, почему бы не собраться там?

Comment: @VerNick: Добавьте ответом для голосования?

Comment: @VladD  У меня нет таланта для написания привлекающих ответов, давайте лучше вы)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Где вы решили собраться?

Comment: @VerNick Видимо, в Праге.

Comment: @VladD Не могли бы вы обновить публикацию, добавив немного конкретики (город, ориентировочные цифры)?

Comment: Я пропустил? =/

Comment: @LEQADA: Да! Но в Мюнхене можно устроить пиво для желающих. :)

Comment: @VladD Итак, когда будет встреча в Мюнхене?

Comment: @RomanPodymov VladD временно недоступен ;) Встреча скорее всего когда-нибудь состоится(в чате недавно были разговоры о "перевстрече" в Мюнхене), но никаких даже приблизительных дат нет. К сожалению(или к счастью, но лично для меня к сожалению) это встреча никаким образом не будет касаться SO(т.е., атрибутики, а также администрации SO там предположительно не будет). Если вы хотите быть в курсе обсуждений встречи, как-то повлиять на встречу, или пообщаться с VladD - велкам, ссылку можно получить через этот [ребус](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8md58.png)(почему так - можете узнать в профиле VladD).

Comment: @LEQADA вы все еще хотите попасть на встречу? ^^^

Comment: @RomanPodymov или проще -> [в этом профиле](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/181100/d-side)

Comment: @AntonSorokin так точно! Спасибо за тег :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

В этом ответе голосуем за Прагу. Прага — красивый и романтичный город, в нём обязательно нужно побывать, так почему не на встрече участников ru.SO?

Comment: Прага - гуд, не так дорого, как Мюнхен, вкусное пиво со свиными коленками и красивые виды :) Смогу или не смогу - зависит от даты сборов.

Comment: И дешёвый, по европейским меркам.

Comment: Интересно, 8 плюсов - это 8 человек, которые готовы приехать? Или просто все хотят в Прагу, но всё равно не поедут?

Comment: @Qwertiy, просто дюжина человек решила где встретиться троим :)

Answer (score 4):

Ещё один вариант для встречи — Амстердам. В этом городе найдётся всё, что угодно, почему бы в нём не найтись места для нескольких русскоязычных программистов?

Comment: Может быть довольно весёлым вариантом

Comment: @alexolut О да.

Comment: @alexolut: Надо же завлечь массы программистов? :)

Answer (score 3):

В этом ответе голосуем за Мюнхен. Мюнхен — отличный город, в нём всегда найдётся пиво для страдающих жаждой участников. А ещё в нём бывает Октоберфест.

Comment: Пиво найдется и в Амстердаме и тем более в Праге :)

Comment: В этом году можно встречу провести в Мюнхене.

Comment: @RomanPodymov скорее всего никто не приедет...

Comment: @XelaNimed Судя по https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8257/Встреча-участников-stack-overflow-на-русском-в-Праге-24-го-ноября-2018-года достаточно 5 участников. Вы бы смогли приехать на встречу в Мюнхен?

Comment: @RomanPodymov пока набирается только 4) Сам Влад, Тим, Xela, и Вы.
UPD: А, не, еще leqada хотел, итого - 5

Comment: @AntonSorokin Влад сообщил, что его не будет.

Comment: @XelaNimed не видел. Видел только то, что вы  все как то договаривались встретится. Может во Флудилку кинете ссылку на то сообщение?

Comment: @RomanPodymov да, конечно :) Но кто будет организовывать? Будет ли кто-то из ruSO? Сколько людей готовы приехать? Где будет проходить встреча?

Comment: @XelaNimed Вы хотели бы посетить встречу в Германии? Или Чехия тоже бы подошла?

Comment: @RomanPodymov лично для меня Германия более предпочтительней, но если сообщество решит встретиться в Чехии, то тоже ничего страшного.