# Встреча участников Stack Overflow на русском в Праге 24-го ноября 2018 года

Tags: обсуждение, встречи-сообщества

С радостью спешу поделиться прекрасной новостью (в продолжение предыдущего обсуждения «[Встреча участников сообщества в Евросоюзе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7993/%D0%92%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%95%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B5)»):

> 24 го ноября (суббота) 2018 года ориентировочно в 15:00 состоится встреча участников сообщества Stack Overflow на русском в красивейшем городе Прага.

Если вы планируете посетить мероприятие, пожалуйста, заполните [форму](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScTRCZKY_MnT0KE3Dmm1TZ3uvpFG5Ri_hVESwZxrHepd3EiKQ/viewform). Она позволит держать вас в курсе. Также у участников встречи есть [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84028).

Приезжайте, мы ждем вас!

Comment: Нет ли желания опубликовать текущее кол-во заполнивших форму участников?

Comment: @älёxölüt, один Nicolas :-D

Comment: @älёxölüt Пока тех, кто подтвердил свое участие трое: VladD, tym32167 и я. Весьма вероятно, что ближе к дате нас будет больше! Буду рад увидеть вас!

Comment: Там же Шенген нужен? =/

Comment: @Suvitruf Да, нужен.

Comment: @Suvitruf сгонять еще раз в Эмираты за Шенгеном теперь ;)

Comment: @älёxölüt я завтра на ДР улетал в другой город. Не до визы =/

Comment: Что там будет? Может канцелярию дадут какую?)

Comment: @entithat Будет много позитива и разговоров о сообществе. Ништяки тоже постараюсь не забыть. Приезжайте! :)

Comment: Как прошло/проходит meeting?

Comment: Когда следующая встреча в Праге намечается? Я только сейчас узнал о том, что такое бывает, с радостью присоединился бы в следующий раз.

Answer (score 22):

Встреча состоялась и длилась более 10 часов :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем большое спасибо, что пришли! Было здорово познакомиться со всеми лично!

Comment: В очках VladD ?

Comment: @avp да, он.  :)

Comment: Деанонимизация удалась ))

Comment: Сейчас бы познакомиться со всеми. `@Nicolas Chabanovsky`, где тут кто?

Comment: Вот черт, совсем я перестал заходить сюда и пропустил. Мог бы присоединиться к вам.

Comment: @andreycha Обидно. Обязательно приходите в следующий раз!

Comment: Вы не могли бы подписать, где кто? Интересно просто узнать :)